# How to get Mouse Coordination in GeoTools?

Tags: geotools

Firstly, i'm sorry that i m  newbiew at Geotools. And i need to tackle  mouse events in Geotools. How can i  get mouse coordination as a Lat and a Lon in geotools?

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to use a MapMouseEvent (http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/swing/event/MapMouseEvent.html)